# How can I stop a particular cell from running in google colab?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

If a cell is taking too long to run (for example, if it has code to train the model in deep learning) , how can I stop it from running in **Google Colab**.

Comment: Ctrl+M+I works for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Press the stop button, or select the 'Interrupt execution' item from the Runtime menu.

[image]

Keep in mind that some code cannot be interrupted. (For example, if you're using a C library stuck in a syscall.) In these cases, you can restart your Python process by selecting 'Restart runtime...' from the Runtime menu.

Comment: what "stop button"?

Comment: The stop button is the one shown in the screenshot above with the tooltip 'Interrupt execution'. It's present when a cell is executing.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a multi-cell file running and you need to stop a particular cell from running. Follow this:

[image: A multicell notebook is running]

Select the code from the google colab cell of interest.

[image: Select the code]

Use ctrl + x to cut the code from the cell (or copy). Delete the cell (this stops the code from executing).

[image: Delete the cell]

Now, create a new cell and paste the code you just copied.

Comment: Please could you use text (or code markup) instead of images of code. We can't copy-and-paste from an image.

Comment: deleting the cell does not stop it from running

Answer (score -1):

write a code cell `1/0` and this will return an error like this:

This is the trick to stop the code from running past this point.

Now you can RUN ALL of notebook.. or from a particular point.. and code will stop at this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-9e1622b385b6> in <module>()
----> 1 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: typing in a cell that is already running doesn't interrupt it

Comment: I don't think it will work. A running cell doesn't stop when we enter text in it.

Comment: I think he wanted to say "insert something that will result in a compilation error", so that cell will stop before being executed.